# Converting nested css to less

Tags: css, less

```
.carView .carList .carContent.carName .icon, .carView .carList .carContent.carFrom .icon {
    padding-inline-end: 0.5rem;
    line-height: normal;
    min-width: 1.2rem;
}
```

I have this css file and would like to change it as Less and also would like to use my existing Less code.

```
.carView {
  .carList {
 
  }
}
```

What I tried is making it like below code.

```
.carView {
  .carList {
    .carContent {
            &.carName .icon, &.carFrom.icon {
                padding-right: 0.5rem;
                line-height: normal;
                min-width: 1.2rem;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach - if you are not trying to increase selector specificity (for example to override third party styling) and you have control over your html - meaning that you know what classes are applied and how - **then you may be able to ignore the parent selectors, remove the nesting altogether  and simply target the icon via its immediate parent.**

The only reason for including the multiple parents is to distinguish the particular element - but its entirely possible that there is only one class of 'carName' - so its irrelevant as to the grandparent of that class. Just the immediate parent  is sufficient to target that class.

```
.carName .icon,
.carFrom .icon {
    padding-inline-end: 0.5rem;
    line-height: normal;
    min-width: 1.2rem;
}
```

alternatively - assuming you have control over the html - then simply **assign a common class (eg: 'carIcon') to all the icons that you want to affect - and style that with no nesting**

```
.carIcon {
    padding-inline-end: 0.5rem;
    line-height: normal;
    min-width: 1.2rem;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was some typos in my prev post. Could you look the updated version?

Comment: The classes are thrid party styling. (Sorry for changing the real name :/) So, I need to nest them with parents classes.

Answer (score 1):

Proper code is:

```less
.carView {
    .carList {
        .carContent.carName .icon,
        .carContent.carFrom .icon {
            padding-inline-end: 0.5rem;
            line-height: normal;
            min-width: 1.2rem;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```less
.carView {
    .carList {
        .carContent {
            &.carName .icon,
            &.carFrom .icon {
                padding-inline-end: 0.5rem;
                line-height: normal;
                min-width: 1.2rem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because `.carContent.carName .icon` and `.carContent.carFrom .icon` are children of `.carView .carList`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to do `.carList.carContent` in your second option, rather than adding an extra layer of nesting? (Or moving it up a level in the first option, since it applies to both child selectors)

Comment: Sorry, there was some typos in my prev post. Could you look the updated version?